# databricks spark - Is cluster itself the reason of low performance?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, databricks, azure-databricks

I've decided to post the question here because I'm out of further ideas. I've been trying to improve performance of my code on many different ways but still facing the same problem.

From the begginning...

- I'm creating dataframe from 700mb csv file (~6mln rows) + caching this data for further processing
- I'm dropping the duplicates basing on 5 columns what gives me the new and lighter dataframe (~3mln rows)
- I'm inputing the new lighter dataframe to my azure sql db via jdbc spark connector (allowing bulk input).

The input process takes almost 9 minutes to complete while previous process takes under the second. I was repartitioning my DF on many different ways and still nothing.

I'm using premium trial version of databricks from azure. It only allowed me to create one type of cluster -> single node, 14gb memory, 4 cores.

I'm relatively new to spark and in my understanding 4 cores means 4 real partitions? So might be this cluster the reason why it takes soo long ? Or maybe I'm missing something and still can improve the process speed.

Here is my code:

## first part:

```
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField, StringType, DateType, DecimalType

weather_schema = StructType([
  StructField("EventId", StringType(), True),
  StructField("Type", StringType(), True),
  StructField("Severity", StringType(), True),
  StructField("StartTime(UTC)", DateType(), True),
  StructField("EndTime(UTC)", DateType(), True),
  StructField("TimeZone", StringType(), True),
  StructField("AirportCode", StringType(), True),
  StructField("LocationLat", DecimalType(18,0), True),
  StructField("LocationLng", DecimalType(18,0), True),
  StructField("City", StringType(), True),
  StructField("Country", StringType(), True),
  StructField("State", StringType(), True),
  StructField("ZipCode", StringType(), True)
  
])

weatherDF = (spark.read
          .option("sep", ",")
          .option("header", True)
          .schema(weather_schema)
          .csv(source+"weather.csv"))

weatherDF.cache()
weatherDF.show()
```

*Command took 0.47 seconds*

## second part:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import count, col, asc

clearedDF = (weatherDF.dropDuplicates(["Type", "Severity", "StartTime(UTC)", "EndTime(UTC)", "City"])
            .orderBy(col("EventId").asc())
            )
```

*Command took 0.03 seconds*

## third part (problematic):

```
jdbcHost = dbutils.secrets.get(scope="adminSecrets", key="dbServer")
jdbcPort = "1433"
jdbcDatabase = dbutils.secrets.get(scope="adminSecrets", key="dbName")
jdbcUrl = "jdbc:sqlserver://{0}:{1};database={2}".format(jdbcHost, jdbcPort, jdbcDatabase)
properties = {
  "user":dbutils.secrets.get(scope="adminSecrets", key="adminLogin"),
  "password":dbutils.secrets.get(scope="adminSecrets", key="adminPassword"),
  "driver" : "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.spark"
}

try:
  (clearedDF.repartition(4).write
    .format(properties["driver"])
    .option("batchsize", 100000)
    .option("tableLock", "true")
    .option("url", jdbcUrl)
    .option("dbtable", "dbo.weather")
    .option("user", properties["user"])
    .option("password", properties["password"])
    .mode("overwrite")
    .save()
  )
except ValueError as error:
  print(str(error))
```

*Command took 8.57 minutes*

Comment: Do you really need `repartition(4)`? But yeah, reaching to an external service tens of times (millions of rows, divided by the batch size) will take some time

Comment: @OneCricketeer Please correct me if I'm wrong. Without adding repartition(4) it takes the same amount of time. It means that spark uses all available resources (cores) by default?

Comment: Assuming you're using `master("local[*]")`, then it'll use all cores. The dataframe itself might have more partitions, though

Comment: So if I'm having 4 cores and dataframes have more partitions than that, then it means that 4 cores have 4 partitions and these 4 partitions have own partitions? My apology for messy explanation but I believe you will catch my point.

Answer (score 0):

pls check the sql server's performance. BTW, what is the row numebr of your df?
Maybe the dropdupliacte also cost some time..